# How to create a rule for auto reply from a specific sender/subject

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I receive an email alert from NMS every day when a link/connection to a branch is down. The subject email for all alerts are same, only the branch code is changed.

For example :

branch code : `A01 and A02`.

Subject email is `" Connection to Branch A01 is Down " or "Connection to Branch A02 is Down"`.

For first handling, I must reply to it and ask the local contact to check devices.

I want to create a rule for auto reply. The body email is the same, but contains different branch code and PIC.

Template for body email is :

Dear `"PIC"`,

based on email alert, Connection to the branch `"A02"` is  down. Please restart the modem, etc.

I want to change PIC and code branch.

Comment: Is the email alert that you receive the same email address ?

Comment: yes, I receive from same email address. addtionally, I want to keep the original message. I tried using "using a specific template" it not include the original message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Script rule and call the following vba.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Rply(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olReply As MailItem

    '// Branch A01
    If InStr(olItem.Subject, "Connection to Branch A01 is Down") Then
        Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
        olReply.Display
        olReply.Body = "Dear PIC " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                       "Based on email alert, Connection to the Branch A01 is down " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                       "Please restart the modem, etc. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        '// Send
        olReply.Send
    Else
        '// Branch A02
        If InStr(olItem.Subject, "Connection to Branch A02 is Down") Then
            Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
            olReply.Display
            olReply.Body = "Dear PIC " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                           "Based on email alert, Connection to the Branch A02 is down " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                           "Please restart the modem, etc. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
            '// Send
            olReply.Send
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a rule in Outlook which may trigger a VBA sub. The sub should look like the following one:

```
Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
  '
End Sub
```

where the mail object represent the incoming email message.

You can use the Outlook object to make any modifications to the item and reply to the item using the [Reply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868875.aspx) method.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: thank you Eugene for your response. Can you provide the basic tutorial using VBA. I'm not understand about it, so i want to know clearly.

Comment: See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

To get the "branch code" and the "PIC", you can use the following string functions:

`Replace` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bt3szac5(v=VS.90).aspx) -> write an replay and set for the "branch code" and the "PIC" a dummy like "%branch%" and "%pic%". Now you replace these dummy’s with the correct information.
`Left` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y050k1wb(v=VS.90).aspx) 
`Right` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dxs6hz0a(v=VS.90).aspx) 
`Mid` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/05e63829(v=VS.90).aspx) -> The three functions `Left`, `Right` and `Mid` can return a part of a string. use it to extract the correct "branch code" and "PIC".

Hope it will help you. kind regards, Nico